# has_one | nested attributes -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, nested-attributes

How would I show one of many nested objects in the index view

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base 

has_many: photos
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos,
 :reject_if => proc { |a| a.all? { |k, v| v.blank?} }


has_one: cover
accepts_nested_attributes_for :cover


end

class Album Controller < ApplicationController
  layout "mini"
  def index
    @albums = Album.find(:all,
    :include => [:cover,]).reverse

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @albums }
    end
  end
```

This is what I have so fare. I just want to show a cover for each album.

Any info on this would be a massive help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view iterate over the nested data. i.e.

```
<% @albums.each do |album| %>

  <%= album.name %>
  <% # display other album details %>

  <%= image_tag album.cover.name %>

  <% album.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= image_tag photo.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller include the `photos` in the query results.

```
@albums = Album.all :include => [:photos]
```

You don't need to include the `:cover` in the query as it is a `has_one` association(unless you are using the fields from `:cover` in your `WHERE` condition).

I suspect you are making the `reverse` call to sort the result-set. Use the `:order` clause instead.

```
@albums = Album.all :include => [:photos], :order => "created_at ASC"
```

OR

```
@albums = Album.all :include => [:photos], :order => "name ASC"
```

Comment: This works well when you have different controllers, but is not working with nested attributes.

getting an error:

undefined local variable or method `photo' for #<Class:0x264c678>